CMake Error: "Generator MinGW Makefiles does not support platform specification, but platform x64 was specified."
build.bat:
@echo off
setlocal

if not exist build (
  mkdir build
)

pushd build

conan install .. --output-folder=. --build=missing

cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
cmake --build .

copy compile_commands.json ..

template.exe

popd

endlocal

conanfile.txt:
[requires]
glfw/3.4
glew/2.2.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain

command ran:
$ ./build.bat

log:
======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=194
os=Windows

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=194
os=Windows


======== Computing dependency graph ========
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: C:/Development/C++/Graphics/GLFW/Template/conanfile.txt
Requirements
    glew/2.2.0#162c9c4b82b196eed6de22764f658d87 - Cache
    glfw/3.4#41cc24c744dc4c80571f5dd10dcd9cda - Cache
    glu/system#a5189f60c8270ac97ed29d7f36fffe39 - Cache
    opengl/system#7c02ea6ef926fd04844af53622a30541 - Cache

======== Computing necessary packages ========
glfw/3.4: Main binary package 'f4d6c37328d2efda18b0804ee64fe81ef802cc45' missing
glfw/3.4: Checking 1 compatible configurations
glfw/3.4: Found compatible package '5d7bb7439775dff9366a392feeb8baeb292a334c': compiler.version=193
glew/2.2.0: Main binary package 'f11bd165005b7981a60f77e1c132942d5ee0d2e1' missing
glew/2.2.0: Checking 1 compatible configurations
glew/2.2.0: Found compatible package '0e5e5c22ac81ba92a302488392437424e738e2e0': compiler.version=193
Requirements
    glew/2.2.0#162c9c4b82b196eed6de22764f658d87:0e5e5c22ac81ba92a302488392437424e738e2e0#298f7914ca2070a14a20936e0c7ca46a - Cache
    glfw/3.4#41cc24c744dc4c80571f5dd10dcd9cda:5d7bb7439775dff9366a392feeb8baeb292a334c#d9ef14f70af6c5758e682c60edf04983 - Cache
    glu/system#a5189f60c8270ac97ed29d7f36fffe39:da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709#0ba8627bd47edc3a501e8f0eb9a79e5e - Cache
    opengl/system#7c02ea6ef926fd04844af53622a30541:da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709#0ba8627bd47edc3a501e8f0eb9a79e5e - Cache

======== Installing packages ========
opengl/system: Already installed! (1 of 4)
glfw/3.4: Already installed! (2 of 4)
glu/system: Already installed! (3 of 4)
glew/2.2.0: Already installed! (4 of 4)
WARN: deprecated: Usage of deprecated Conan 1.X features that will be removed in Conan 2.X:
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.filenames' used in: opengl/system

======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ========
conanfile.txt: Writing generators to C:/Development/C++/Graphics/GLFW/Template/build
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeDeps' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeDeps necessary find_package() and targets for your CMakeLists.txt
    find_package(glfw3)
    find_package(glew)
    target_link_libraries(... glfw GLEW::GLEW)
conanfile.txt: Generator 'CMakeToolchain' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain: Preset 'conan-default' added to CMakePresets.json.
    (cmake>=3.23) cmake --preset conan-default
    (cmake<3.23) cmake <path> -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake  -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: C:/Development/C++/Graphics/GLFW/Template/build/CMakePresets.json
conanfile.txt: CMakeToolchain generated: C:/Development/C++/Graphics/GLFW/Template/CMakeUserPresets.json
conanfile.txt: Generating aggregated env files
conanfile.txt: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat']
Install finished successfully
-- Using Conan toolchain: C:/Development/C++/Graphics/GLFW/Template/build/conan_toolchain.cmake
-- Conan toolchain: CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET=v143
-- Conan toolchain: Setting CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY=$<$<CONFIG:Release>:MultiThreadedDLL>
-- Conan toolchain: C++ Standard 14 with extensions OFF
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Generator

    MinGW Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error:
  Generator

    MinGW Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


The system cannot find the file specified.
'template.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project): would seem to be significant. Perhaps you should edit-in CMakeLists.txt

You need to specify the cmake generator in your Conan profile https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/14209#issuecomment-1616189623

@Magoo: Problems in environment are usually detected during the project() call in CMake, thus the error stack. In the current case it is clear that the problem is about mixing MinGW Makefiles generator in the command line with the Conan toolchain created for Visual Studio. That is, content of CMakeLists.txt is irrelevant to the given problem.

@Tsyvarev : Mixing mingw into batch is nothing short of barbaric.

The Conan profile is not aligned with your current compiler or generator.
To use MinGW, the Conan profile should be something like:
[settings]
os=Windows
arch=x86_64
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=11
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
...

Depending of what you have in the PATH, you might need to add the compiler path, etc, to the environment:
[buildenv]
PATH=+(path)C:/path/to/my/mingw/bin

For further details, including how MinGW from a Conan package with a tool_requires can be done see this page
